# Userform Date not showing up in the correct format in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that has a textbox called 'DateBox'. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    DateBox.Value = Format(Date, "d/m/yy")
```

On form submit, I have the following code to update Sheet1's first empty cell with the Date as per the form.

```
   Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateBox.Value
```

However, instead of d/m/yy, the spreadsheet shows m/d/yy. I have done some search and understand that this has something to do with the regional settings. I'm not sure changing the settings will be helpful for me as this form will be used by different groups of people with possibly different settings.

I would like to know if there is a way I can hard code the date to appear in the desired format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA is US-EN centric and when it comes to dates it wants to assume `MM/DD/YYYY` when it tries to convert a string to a date.

First we want to force the date by parsing the string coming in from the textbox:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateSerial(Split(DateBox.Value,"/")(2),Split(DateBox.Value,"/")(1),Split(DateBox.Value,"/")(0))
```

Then format the cell after parsing the date:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).NumberFormat = "d/m/yy"
```

Or consider using a more accepted format for the date `dd mmm, yyyy` in your datebox.  This makes it less ambiguous.

Thanks to chris neilsen for his help.

Comment: this works very well for me. Thank you so much for sharing the solution.